# Translating Apps

Tags: translation, contributing

Firstly, I've got to (openly) express what I think about this community, and the Ubuntu project in general: it's simply great ;) Good job!
I'd therefore like to contribute the Ubuntu Community. I only know bits of programming and am starting now, but in the meanwhile I'd also like to help translating stuff: I speak German, English and Italian.
So I looked a little bit, but couldn't find much, except this:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/Internationalisation/TranslationProcess
..which didn't really help me any further :)
Does anybody know anything 'bout this?
Thanx to you all who take the time to read and the effort to answer!

Answer (score 0):

lol, I'd never seen that page. I have previously contributed via the Launchpad Translations site: https://translations.launchpad.net/